# Can I use Auth0 Lock with Nuxt.js Auth Package?

Tags: vue.js, nuxt.js, auth0, nuxt-auth, auth0-lock

I'm currently working on a nuxt.js project than has a login with an auth0 server

I've used the [nuxtjs-auth package](https://auth.nuxtjs.org/providers/auth0/) with the auth0 package and is working fine

The problem I'm currently having is than my project is in a language not currently supported by [Auth0 Universal Login](https://auth0.com/docs/i18n/universal-login-internationalization) and in this cases the recommendation is to do the login with the [Lock.js library](https://auth0.com/docs/libraries/lock) from Auth0

My question is: It is possible to use Lock.js library with Nuxt Auth Library as a [custom scheme](https://auth.nuxtjs.org/guide/scheme/#creating-your-own-scheme)? Or it is better to remove the Nuxt Auth plugin and do all the logic by myself?

I've found a project in Github with a [basic implementation of Lock in nuxt.js](https://github.com/adystag/nuxt-auth0-lock) but it's not using Nuxt Auth

Thanks!

Comment: Did you tried this one? https://auth.nuxtjs.org/providers/auth0

Comment: @kissu Yes! Thats how my project is working now, the thing is with this strategy the guests are redirected to auth0 login page and I can't translate that page as the language i need is not on the supported languages :(

Comment: They do not have any i18n? Damn.. Can you even make it work by not going to their page? If you do, I guess that you'll need to do it manually yep.